# Minecraft gift card/code

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Is there a Minecraft gift card/code that allows you to buy better weapons in-game?
My stepson is obsessed. I can't work out whether gift cards/codes just buy you the game or allow you to purchase better weapons in-game?

I'm in Australia.

Comment: <spam>If you're still interested in gifting him something minecraft related, [thinkgeek has a variety of minecraft-related products](http://www.thinkgeek.com/interests/minecraft/?pfm=Search&t=minecraft). [The minecraft website also has its own store section](https://minecraft.net/store).</spam>

Comment: This will certainly be yes in the future when Microsoft introduces DLC

Answer (score 9):

No, Minecraft does not have any form of micro transactions (buying weapons/cosmetic items). Gift cards are solely for obtaining the game.

Besides, part of the fun of the game is making the weapons.

Comment: Wait until Microsoft releases the Minecraft DLC system...

Comment: Don't even joke about that :|

Comment: If that ever happens I'll be quitting Minecraft

Comment: @KevinvanderVelden but it's true